# how to open system apps using OS in python?

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

I wanted to open apps like calculator, camera, and other apps using the python OS module
how can I use the os.startfile() function to open apps like this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple

```py
import os
os.system("program_name") # To open any program by their name recognized by windows
#for example
os.system("notepad")
```

There you go

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the **os** module

```
import  os
# call startfile method to “start” a file with its associated (default) program
os.startfile(filepath)
```